# Empty unique-pointer calls destructor upon leaving scope

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

So I've written some code to try out the smart pointers that come with the c++ std library. To do this i made a test class `MyClass`that generates console output upon destruction. My Code looks like this:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> getMyClassPtr(int a = 0, char b = 'a', double c = 1.1)
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> ptr = std::make_unique<MyClass>(MyClass(a, b, c));
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> pMyClass = getMyClassPtr();

    if (pMyClass)
        std::cout << "MyClass Values:\na = " << pMyClass->getA() << "\nb = "
          << pMyClass->getB() << "\nc = " << pMyClass->getC() << "\n";
}
```

Now what I stumble on, is that the destructor of `MyClass`is called at the end of `main`, but also at the end of `getMyClassPtr()`by the now empty pointer.

Which object is being destroyed here?

It just seems odd to me that the destructor of an object is called but is not really gone. Is the object being copied?

Comment: `std::make_unique<MyClass>(MyClass(a, b, c))` should be `std::make_unique<MyClass>(a, b, c)`. What you're seeing is that additional temporary being destructed.

Comment: It really was that easy, huh? Thanks Quentin

Answer (score 0):

`getMyClassPtr()` should return as follow : `std::move(ptr);` else `ptr` is deleted when the scope of the `getMyClassPtr` is reach.

You can also refactor you function to return it as reference, and then the std::move is not mandatory, but its not a good practice.

```
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> getMyClassPtr(int a = 0, char b = 'a', double c = 1.1)
{
    return std::move(std::make_unique<MyClass>(MyClass(a, b, c)));
}
```

Comment: Since a unique pointer can't be copied, the compiler will automatically move it for the return. No explicit move needed.

Comment: I tired this real quick, and the destructor is still called at the end of `getMyClassPtr()`. Quentin's comment to do `std::make_unique<MyClass>(a, b, c)` instead of `std::make_unique<MyClass>(MyClass(a, b, c))`worked, though.

Comment: This is incorrect. You do not move from local variables. At best it does nothing and at worst it prevents a copy elision.

Comment: `ptr` doesn't get deleted. Like every local object, it gets **destroyed** (i.e., its destructor is called) when it goes out of scope. That **always** happens; it does not depend on whether you use `std::move` on it.